# Catching up after final round of interviews?

Tags: interviewing, rejection

I work at a company as an intern, and they recently told me they have an opening for a full time job for someone at my level. Someone recommended me internally, so I applied and easily got through the first interview, which went amazing. The second interview went great too. I was supposed to get an answer on Friday, but the person got sick and I won't see her until Tuesday. She sent me an email asking me to have a half hour meeting with her to "catch up".

I very much think this will be a rejection, but they're being nice since I already work there so they thought they'd tell me in person. If they wanted to offer me the job, it wouldn't take half an hour, right?

So I'm guessing it's just so that they can explain why they went for someone else.
What do you guys think?

Comment: If you got accepted, they may well want to take half an hour to explain the new role to you, give you relevant paperwork and let you ask your questions. This may be an impromptu interview if they still want to give you a last round. Maybe it's just that she/he had half an hour to fill. Half an hour is a convenient placeholder time for all sorts of things. Don't read too much into it. Just be glad this is a company that likes doing things in person with its employees - nothing is colder than an email.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based: the only people that can really answer this are your HR department, and you're going to find out the answer in 48 hours anyway.

Comment: You're assuming the worst. Don't do that. I agree with Akshat - they have probably selected you and want to discuss things that the person couldn't as she was sick.

Answer (score 2):

See her on Tuesday. You would not know for sure until you see them. If they reject you, move on. If they accept you, congratulations. Unless you see other signs they might reject you, you should simply assume she went sick, that's all.